# AJAX Crawling with Express on static routes

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I have a static route for

```
/public/slides/lecture1.html#!3
```

which displays the third div element (other `div` HTMLelements will have `display:none;`) of lecture1.html.

I use Express `app.use(express.static(WEBROOT));` and everything works fine. But I want to be able to make that slide AJAX Crawable so I want to react on request which looks like this:

```
/public/slides/lecture1.html?_escaped_fragment_=3
```

and return single page with only that one `div` element - so that Google would index texts from slide 3 in lecture1.html properly.

How do I do that using Express?

Is it possible to add GET request handler on link which is already served by express.static?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talked on IRC, this wouldn't be in the "static route" category (I mean you won't be serving this with express.static).

What you would do is create an Express route and render that file based on your query variables:

```
app.get('/lecture1.html', function (req, res) {
  if (req.query._escaped_fragment_ == 3) { 
    // .. do something..
  } else {
    // render lecture1.html here
    // you can just rename the file lecture1.ejs
    // move it to the views directory
    // and then render it like res.render('lecture1.ejs');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I've meant. The solution is to move Static handler after other handlers. Then I can check if there's fragment and if not then `next();` to serve file statically.

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/OptimalBits/Crawlme. It is an express middleware that handles this automatically. Just do this and you're ajax-crawlable:

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  http = require('http'),
  crawlme = require('crawlme');

var app = express()
  .use(crawlme())
  .use(express.static(__dirname + '/webroot'));

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the req.query property to access the query string in an express request.